# URL Routing: How do I have a string as my id?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

I would like to receive a string as the id in the URL. Here is an example:

```
http://www.example.com/Home/Portal/Fishing
```

I would like to have Fishing in my id. But I cannot achieve it with the following code:

Code from my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Portal(string name)
{
    // some code
    ViewData["Portal Name"] = name;
}
```

Code from Global.asax.cs:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
  "Default", // Route name
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
  );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just change the argument to `id`:

```
public ActionResult Portal(string id)
{
    // some code
    ViewData["Portal Name"] = id;
}
```

The argument will be bound if it has the same name as the route value token. So an alternate approach would be to keep the argument named `name` and change the route:

```
public ActionResult Portal(string name)
{
    // some code
    ViewData["Portal Name"] = name;
}

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{name}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", name = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

I would choose using `id`, though, as it's the more standard approach.